# I have an app service plan and 4 app services. All the app services use the same app service plan

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have 1 app service plan arm template and 4 app sevice arm templates.My requirement is i need to deploy the app service plan first and need to deploy the 4 app services individually.how can i archive that

Comment: Could you elaborate your issue? Did you use Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to deploy into Azure App Service using Azure DevOps CI/CD Pipeline, you could use [Azure App Service Deploy task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=azure-devops) in the pipeline.

Comment: Any update to this issue? Is my reply helpful?